# Yolov7, CUDA device

Tags: yolo, yolov5

I can not teach, run YOLov7 on my CUDA device.
Everything works well when using the CPU. Nothing works on the video card.
graphics card: GTH 1060 3GB

console output:

```
`C:\pythonProject\yolo\yolov7>python detect.py --weights runs/train/exp3/weights/best.pt --img 1920 --conf-thres 0.3 --save-txt --source test.mp4
```

```
C:\Users\Kot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:30: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\Kot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.EL2C6PLE4ZYW3ECEVIV3OXXGRN2NRFM2.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\Kot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.GK7GX5KEQ4F6UYO3P26ULGBQYHGQO7J4.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"
Namespace(weights=['runs/train/exp3/weights/best.pt'], source='test.mp4', img_size=1920, conf_thres=0.3, iou_thres=0.45, device='', view_img=False, save_txt=True, save_conf=False, nosave=False, classes=None, agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, update=False, project='runs/detect', name='exp', exist_ok=False, no_trace=False)
YOLOR  v0.1-121-g2fdc7f1 torch 1.13.1+cu116 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB, 3071.75MB)

Fusing layers...
RepConv.fuse_repvgg_block
RepConv.fuse_repvgg_block
RepConv.fuse_repvgg_block
IDetect.fuse
C:\Users\Kot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py:504: UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\native\TensorShape.cpp:3191.)
  return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
Model Summary: 314 layers, 36487166 parameters, 6194944 gradients, 103.2 GFLOPS
 Convert model to Traced-model...
 traced_script_module saved!
 model is traced!

video 1/1 (1/19218) C:\pythonProject\yolo\yolov7\test.mp4: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonProject\yolo\yolov7\detect.py", line 196, in <module>
    detect()
  File "C:\pythonProject\yolo\yolov7\detect.py", line 92, in detect
    pred = non_max_suppression(pred, opt.conf_thres, opt.iou_thres, classes=opt.classes, agnostic=opt.agnostic_nms)
  File "C:\pythonProject\yolo\yolov7\utils\general.py", line 684, in non_max_suppression
    i = torchvision.ops.nms(boxes, scores, iou_thres)  # NMS
  File "C:\Users\Kot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torchvision\ops\boxes.py", line 41, in nms
    return torch.ops.torchvision.nms(boxes, scores, iou_threshold)
  File "C:\Users\Kot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\_ops.py", line 442, in __call__
    return self._op(*args, **kwargs or {})
NotImplementedError: Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'torchvision::nms' is only available for these backends: [CPU, QuantizedCPU, BackendSelect, Python, FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode, Functionalize, Named, Conjugate, Negative, ZeroTensor, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradXLA, AutogradMPS, AutogradXPU, AutogradHPU, AutogradLazy, Tracer, AutocastCPU, AutocastCUDA, FuncTorchBatched, FuncTorchVmapMode, Batched, VmapMode, FuncTorchGradWrapper, PythonTLSSnapshot, FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode, PythonDispatcher].

CPU: registered at C:\Users\circleci\project\torchvision\csrc\ops\cpu\nms_kernel.cpp:112 [kernel]
QuantizedCPU: registered at C:\Users\circleci\project\torchvision\csrc\ops\quantized\cpu\qnms_kernel.cpp:124 [kernel]
BackendSelect: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\BackendSelectFallbackKernel.cpp:3 [backend fallback]
Python: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:140 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\functorch\DynamicLayer.cpp:488 [backend fallback]
Functionalize: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\FunctionalizeFallbackKernel.cpp:291 [backend fallback]
Named: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\NamedRegistrations.cpp:7 [backend fallback]
Conjugate: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\ConjugateFallback.cpp:18 [backend fallback]
Negative: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\native\NegateFallback.cpp:18 [backend fallback]
ZeroTensor: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\ZeroTensorFallback.cpp:86 [backend fallback]
ADInplaceOrView: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:64 [backend fallback]
AutogradOther: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:35 [backend fallback]
AutogradCPU: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:39 [backend fallback]
AutogradCUDA: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:47 [backend fallback]
AutogradXLA: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:51 [backend fallback]
AutogradMPS: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:59 [backend fallback]
AutogradXPU: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:43 [backend fallback]
AutogradHPU: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:68 [backend fallback]
AutogradLazy: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\VariableFallbackKernel.cpp:55 [backend fallback]
Tracer: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\torch\csrc\autograd\TraceTypeManual.cpp:296 [backend fallback]
AutocastCPU: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\autocast_mode.cpp:482 [backend fallback]
AutocastCUDA: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\autocast_mode.cpp:324 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchBatched: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\functorch\LegacyBatchingRegistrations.cpp:743 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchVmapMode: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\functorch\VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:28 [backend fallback]
Batched: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\BatchingRegistrations.cpp:1064 [backend fallback]
VmapMode: fallthrough registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\VmapModeRegistrations.cpp:33 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchGradWrapper: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\functorch\TensorWrapper.cpp:189 [backend fallback]
PythonTLSSnapshot: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:148 [backend fallback]
FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode: registered at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\p
```

ytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\functorch\DynamicLayer.cpp:484 [backend fallback]
PythonDispatcher: registered at C:\actions-runner_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:144 [backend fallback]`

using the cpu everything is fine. With a video card, a complete collapse